# In Netty 4.1, when are the handlers in the pipeline removed after closing the channel on the server?

Tags: java, netty, nio

So, we are in the process of migrating from Netty 3.9 to Netty 4.1 on our production servers. There seems to be a difference in the way the `ChannelHandler`s are added and removed from the pipeline in both the versions. Specifically, after closing a channel on the server, I am logging the `ChannelHandler`s present in the pipeline at some point. While in Netty 4.1, the pipeline sometimes shows few or none of the handlers, in Netty 3.9, all the handlers are always present. All this after closing the channel reference. Is this expected? When does Netty (both in 3.9 and 4.1) remove all the handlers in the pipeline after a channel is closed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In netty 4.x we remove all the handlers after each other from the pipeline when a channel is closed. This way we also execute `handlerRemoved(...)` which may is needed to release memory etc.

Comment: Thanks Norman. Few more doubts: Does this happen in an 'asyc' way of some sort? Maybe in a background thread or something? Because sometimes I still see my encoder and decoder for few channels after closing them. Also this mechanism of removing handlers after closing a channel isn't present in Netty 3.x?

Comment: yes this may happen in an async fashion and yes this is not present in 3.x